# Returning an object from Web Service to Ajax Request success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, ajax-request

Hello Fellow Developers,

I have a SSN textbox that onblur calls a function which does an ajax request to a Web Method to decide if an employee has been previously hired.

The Web Method returns a TermedEmployee Object to the success callback, but I'm unsure how to parse the object.

```
 $('#<%=FormView1.FindControl("SSNField").ClientID%>').blur(hideValue);

 hideValue = function (ev) {
 var $this = $(this);

 $this.data('value', $this.val());
 $('#<%=FormView1.FindControl("hiddenSSN").ClientID%>').val($this.val());

   var data2Send = '{"SSN": ' + $this.val() + ' }';
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "AuthforHire.aspx/EmployeeisRehire",
       data: data2Send,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {

           var obj = JSON.stringify(result.d);


           if (obj.IsTermed) {
              $('#%=RadWindowRehire.ContentContainer.FindControl("TextBoxTermID").ClientID%>').val(arg.d);       
                 var wndWidth = 900;
                 var wndHeight = 500;
                 var wnd = window.radopen(null, "RadWindowRehire");



             }

         },
         error: function (xhr) {
             alert('Form update failed. ');  //error occurred
         }

     });
```

**Below is a minified version of my webMethod, which works correctly**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static TermedEmployee EmployeeisRehire(string SSN)
{ 
 TermedEmployee termedEmp = new TermedEmployee();
// Db call to get necessary data.

   termedEmp.Name = dr["name"];
   termedEmp.TermDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TermDate"].ToString());
   ......
 }
```

So How Can I extract Name, TermDate,StartDate, ReasonforTerm, etc from the object returned to the callback function?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line in your success callback is:

```
var obj = JSON.stringify(result.d);
```

Which is trying to serialize what ASP.Net will already have serialized for you.
Change this to:

```
var obj = result.d;
```

And you will then have access to `obj.Name`, `obj.TermDate` and all the other properties by name.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting an undefined value of obj.Termdate then an error pops up saying "Invalid Character". Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Yes.  I edited the response, no need to use JSON.parse since the result.d already contains your object, and not a string representation of it.  You can stick a breakpoint or a debugger statement in your success callback and inspect the response with firebug or visual studio if that's what you're using.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick @Dimitri! Once converting it to an obj seems like I have full access! I can't thank you enough for your time and patience! God Bless!